# no longer a 2-D list after $.get() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I used:

```
$.get(theURL, function( my_var ) {
    $('#result').append('<h3>'+my_var+'</h3><p>');
}, 'text');
```

to retrieve the content of theURL which is actually a 2-D list similar to

```
[["David",1,4,"Smith"],["Jane",5,3,"Doe"]];
```

and `my_var` shows up in HTML as intended, but when I try to access list elements such as "David" using `my_var[0][0]`, it does not work, and `my_var[0]` prints "[" as it get treated as a long string, is there a way to retrive this 2-D list and parse them as an object?

Comment: Use `JSON` datatype instead of `text` i.e. `$.get(theURL, function( my_var ) {
  //Iterate my_var
 }, 'json');`

Comment: @Satpal the content of the URL isn't in JSON format though, so if I change text to json, it will fire off the fail function instead and thus nothing gets shown on my HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can remove the `;` from your result string and then just parse it with JSON

```js
var result = '[["David",1,4,"Smith"],["Jane",5,3,"Doe"]]';
console.log(JSON.parse(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `[` by using `my_var[0][0]` which means it is in the string format.

If you want to get `David` then you have to parse it into json and then you can access the same as shown below

```
$.parseJSON(my_var)[0][0];
```

This will give `David` as an output.

Comment: parsing gives error as the source file is not proper JSON format though.. the orignal URL gives 2-D list and I cannot modify the source.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.getJSON` instead of `$.get`. It will then automatically parse the response as JSON rather than leave it as a string.